# "refer to something by" or "refer to something as"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

> The machine selects a single variable X (we refer to the latter by the
>   machine's selected variable)

Or

> The machine selects a single variable X (we refer to the latter as the
>   machine's selected variable)

My question:

1) Does the sentence seem correct?

2) Shall I use `refer to .. by` or `refer to .. as` ?

3) Can I replace `refere to .. as` or `refer to .. by`  by the word `aka`? Note that I am the one who is giving them these names for use in my paper.

Comment: FYI, it appears that both sentences are identical - did you mean to replace "by" with "as" in one of them?

Comment: @Mixolydian corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that normally you would use "as" if you were to follow with a specific name (the exact term you are replacing the original term with), and "by" if you were to follow with a description of the replacement term.

For instance:

> We refer to him *by* nickname.
>
> We refer to him *as* "Bob".

In your case, I am not sure what you mean by "the latter" as I don't see more than one item you're talking about. If what you are trying to say is that you will use "the machine's selected variable" in place of "X" in the rest of the paper, then this is how I would phrase it:

> The machine selects a single variable X (we refer to *this* *as* the machine's selected variable)

You can also use "AKA" in place of "we refer to ... as ", but this would be more informal.

Comment: Sorry for my brevity that led to clarity. The exact sentence is like this: `The machine selects a version v and a variable X (we refer to the latter as the machine's selected variable)`. Because the machine selects two things, while I only need to use the term `selected variable` throughout the paper. So does the `latter` still make sense after my clarification?

Comment: @user9371654 yep - that makes total sense now - thanks for the clarification! By the way, I think you meant to say "Sorry for my brevity that led to *confusion*", as what I had before was the opposite of clarity. Now it is clear and I have clarity. :) Anyway, this sounds fine - or just say "the selected variable" if the fact that it comes from the machine is understood and you're not actually using "machine's" as part of the phrase later on.